# Verify cron daemon is enabled in Slackware 14.2

Tags: cron, daemon, slackware, start-stop-daemon, slackbuilds

How will I know if `cron` daemon is running in my Slackware installation? I tried the code below and it returns me nothing. It means `cron` is not in `/etc/rc.d` folder.

```
ls /etc/rc*.d | grep crond
```

Comment: Enabled or running?

Comment: @JeffSchaller-> Identify if it is running. If it is not, atleast enable.

Comment: Can you try `ps -ef | grep cron` and see if it returns anything?

Comment: Which cron?  Williamson?  Dillon?  Vixie?  Guenter?  Godouet?  Jackson?  Mašláňová?

Comment: @Haxiel  -> yes it has 2 outputs: (1st line) root     1101     1    0    00:26    ?    00:00:00    /usr/sbin/crond -l notice  (2nd line)  root 1284 1157 0    01:01 tty1    00:00:000 grep cron   . What does it mean?

Comment: @Eliyah The `ps` command shows running processes, and that first line is your cron daemon. So yes, the cron daemon is currently running on your system.

Answer (score 2):

On Slackware some daemons/services do not have separate script in `/etc/rc.d/` directory and are run directly from `/etc/rc.d/rc.M` script (or `rc.S` when you start not in multiuser but single mode). Try:

```
grep /etc/rc.d/ -r -e "cron"
```

So it's running by default on Slackware, unless you comment it out manually in `rc.M`.

Also on Slackware only `rc.d` is used. You can ignore all `rc[0-6].d` directories. This directories are provided only to ease your pain if you install some non-Slackware packages that crash without them.